# QGIS - Can't select Inputs for Select by Location algorithm in Graphical Modeler?

Tags: algorithm, qgis-modeler, select-by-location, input

All the other questions I've seen so far are a step ahead of me. I've defined an Input for a vector layer, and am trying to use the Select by Location Algorithm. I typed the name of my Input, but the modeler doesn't seem interested in connecting it. Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: Which Version of QGIS? (3.14 was only recently released - it may have improvements in this area) https://qgis.org/en/site/

Comment: Err mine's at 3.6.1-Noosa! 
In any event, would that impact what seems like a fairly straightforward algorithm? I tried some other algorithms and I was able to select my created input, but seems strange that this specific one doesn't want to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it - I initially left the geometry type as "Not Required" - selected Polygon and now I can interact with it.

Comment: I'm actually having the same problem, and this solution does not seem to help. I have defined the type of the vector layer in the input, but I still don't seem to be able to select as a parameter for subsequent algorithms. Typing in the name of the parameter manually also doesn't seem to help. Do you have any further thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Update for QGIS 3.14 - from [QGIS graphical modeller joining input layers to processing algorithms](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/372821/qgis-graphical-modeller-joining-input-layers-to-processing-algorithms?rq=1)

To select something else that a layer in the current project - such as model input, or output of another algorithm in the current model - the category of input has to be defined first using the '123' button:

[image]