# QGIS graphical modeller joining input layers to processing algorithms

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I am trying to learn how to use the graphical modeler application in QGIS 3.14

I have encountered a problem early on. If I pull vector layers into the modeler canvas and then add in an algorithm to act on the layer, when I try to set the input within the algorithm dialogue, the layer as added to the modeler canvas is not available in the input drop-down list of the algorithm. Only layers added into the QGIS map canvas seem to be available. As such when I close the algorithm dialogue box no input link is established on the modeler canvas between the input and the algorithm, as various tutorials indicate should happen.

[image]

Am I missing something very simple here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, thats basically some simple stuff that has changed in 3.14. You are doing it correctly for older versions.

Since 3.14 you first need to click on the "123" field just on the left and select "model input". Then you can choose your Model-Input-Layer from the dropdown menu.

Comment: yes .. thought it would be a simple thing .. though I couldn't find it. I thought that I was following the latest version of the QGIS tutorial as well. Thanks for your help